# Generated code via Emscripten doesn't return values

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I try to implement a very simple example to return values from an array. My example seems simple but I couldn't understand why it is not working:

This my code in C++

```
static int results[20];

extern "C" {
    void setValue(int index, int value {
        results[index] = value;
    }
    int getValue (int index) {
        return results[index];
    }
};
```

My code in .html:

```
Module.ccall('setValue',null,['number','number'],1,1);
var val = Module.ccall('getValue','number',['number'],1);
```

My command for compiling:

```
emcc --bind -o face_quick_example.js face_quick_example.cpp -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_setValue','_getValue']"
```

I checked the tutorial and some stackoverflow answers, but I couldn't it do working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `ccall` the arguments to be passed to the C function must be inside an array, so your JavaScript for calling `setValue` and `getValue` should be:

```
Module.ccall('setValue', null, ['number', 'number'], [1, 1]);
var val = Module.ccall('getValue', 'number', ['number'], [1]);
```